# Question about relative motion from "A Brief History of Time"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, relative-motion, galilean-relativity

I read this example in Stephen Hawking's *A Brief History of Time*:

> If one sets aside for a moment the rotation of the Earth and its orbit round the Sun, one could say that the Earth was at rest and that a train on it was traveling north at ninety miles per hour or that the train was at rest and the Earth was moving south at ninety miles per hour. If one carried out experiments with moving bodies on the train, all Newton’s laws would still hold. For instance, playing ping-pong on the train, one would find that the ball obeyed Newton’s laws just like a ball on a table by the track. So there is no way to tell whether it is the train or the Earth that is moving.

I can't understand this please can anyone tell me about this?

Comment: Which bit are you confused about?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Stack Exchange.  You've asked a question that goes to the heart of all physics.  We are on the earth that is rotating at a very high speed, but you can't tell.  The earth itself is circling around the sun at an even higher speed, but you can't tell.  The sun is circling the centre of our galaxy at an even higher speed, but you can't tell.  And the galaxy is moving through space at an even higher speed, but you can't tell.  So it makes sense that if you were on a perfectly smooth train ride, with the windows blacked out, you wouldn't be able to tell.   In all of these cases you can play ping-pong, or throw a football to your friend and it behaves exactly as if you were not moving at all.    But if that train turned a corner on the track, then yes, you would be able to tell.   The football would move in a straight line while you and your friend turned away from it. This is the difference between an inertial and non-inertial reference frame.

Comment: ...and for that we have Einstein and his trusty elevator

Answer (score 0):

To make this simple, it means that we cannot determine what is moving just by Newton's laws.